# Is it correct to write the whole number $2$ as a mixed fraction $1 \dfrac{1}{1}$ or $2 \dfrac{0}{1}$?

Tags: fractions, integers

So if we start from writing $2$ as an improper fraction, and use the same procedure for any improper fraction to covert it to a mixed number, we'll get $2\dfrac{0}{1}$. Which makes sense, and it can be reverted back to $2$.
\begin{align}
2\rightarrow\dfrac{2}{1}\rightarrow 2\dfrac{0}{1}
\end{align}
But from playing around with this, I also found that there's another mixed number that can be evaluated to $2$. Starting from $1+\dfrac{1}{1}$
$$1+\dfrac{1}{1}\rightarrow1\dfrac{1}{1}\rightarrow\dfrac{2}{1}\rightarrow2$$

So, $2$ can be represented as either $2\dfrac01$ or $1\dfrac11$.
Are both these correct?

Comment: Unusual, but valid representations of $2$

Comment: I like how I've never seen this being written except for 7th grade math class.

Comment: It seems to me that the same way you get $1\dfrac11=2$ you can also get $1\dfrac21=3$, $1\dfrac32 = 2.5$, and $2\dfrac{15}4=5.75.$ That is, if you release the usually assumed constraint that the numerator in a mixed number is always strictly less than the denominator, you can get many alternative representations for rational numbers, especially when the numbers are large.

Comment: The real question, I think, is whether mixed numbers are merely subject to mathematical rules, or are they subject to customary rules of usage that come from non-mathematical domains such as labeling of food items? There seem to be specific motivations for writing mixed fractions that contradict the idea of writing either $\dfrac11$ or even $\dfrac01$ as a fractional part, namely that we are trying to make it **easier** to compare a rational value to an integer written in the simplest form, and the integer written in the simplest form is always the easiest thing to compare with itself.

Answer (score 2):

I would just write $2$, and reserve the use of mixed fractions for non-integers. Both your options look strange and unusual, but I don't think either of them is wrong.